# uniqueness of ODE Problem by Picard-Lindelöf

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:[0,1] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(t,y) = \sin^2(ty) + t$ and the initial value problem $y'=f(t,y)$ with $y(0) = 0$. I have to show that a unique solution exists  on $[0,1]$ and compute it.

We can just show that by Picards-Lindelöf theorem, since f is continous as the sum of continous functions, that the function is globally lipschitz continous with constant $L=1$ because of $ |f(t,y) - f(t,x)| = |\sin^2(ty) - \sin^2(tx)|\leq L|y-x|$ for $t \in[0,1]$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$  , right? Moreover the solution of the ODE is just given by the fundamental theorem of calculus by just integrating the equation?

I just wanted to make sure that my reasoning is correct! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mostly you have to use Picard's iteration to compute the solution.

Comment: Your Lipschitz constant is wrong, you are missing the factor from the derivative of the square. For the claim itself, mainly that the solution exists on the whole of $[0,1]$, it is indeed sufficient that a global Lipschitz constant exists.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann, factor from derivative comes from applying the mean value theorem, right? And just integrating is not enough for the solution?

Comment: Yes, $\sin^2(tx)-\sin^2(tx)=2\sin(tc)\cos(tc)·t(y-x)$ for some midpoint $c$. The standard version of P-L only gives local existence. One can then either cobble together a solution over the full interval, or modify the construction for the fixed-point theorem so that it directly results in solutions over the full interval. Both variants depend on the global Lipschitz constant. // PS: Seeing the printed formula, it is obvious that $2\sin(tc)\cos(tc)=\sin(2tc)$, which invalidates that part of my first comment.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was very helpful!